# AngularJS - ng-repeat to display empty cell/s when data is not available

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple `ng-repeat` that loops through a JSON file with a list of countries and details about that country e.g. currency, population for a particular set of months (24 in this case)

My `ng-repeat` loops through the first 12 months successfully, and displaying the corresponding text when the `ng-switch` criteria is met.

The issue i am facing, is that for some countries, we there is less than 12months worth of data, in some cases, only 3 months.

What i am struggling to do, is that if there is not sufficient data available, to display an empty cell.

**Here's my `ng-repeat`:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in Countries[key]">
    <th>{{country.countryName}}</th>

    <td ng-repeat="countryDetails in country.Details.slice(0, 12)" ng-switch="countryDetails.Population">
        <span ng-switch-when="10000">Medium</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="20000">Large</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="30000">Larger</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="40000">Very Large</span>
        <span ng-switch-default>Error</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle similar to your case and fixed it like this:

```
<td ng-repeat="countryDetails in country.Details.slice(0, 12)" 
ng-switch="countryDetails">
    <span ng-switch-when="11">Medium</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="22">Large</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="33">Larger</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="44">Very Large</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>Error</span>
</td>
<td ng-repeat="emptyCell in getEmptyCells(country.Details.length)">
    empty
</td>
```

#### JS

```
$scope.getEmptyCells = function(len){
    var emptyCells = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 12 - len; i++){
        emptyCells.push(i);
    }        
    return emptyCells;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GkarV/337/)

Comment: great answer, can your solution be achieved through a directive?

Comment: @OamPsy Yeah you can implement this using a directive but using a controller function is more straightforward I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom range in your scope:

```
$scope.range = function(n) {
    return new Array(n);
};
```

And then loop with it on your `country.Details` array

```
<td ng-repeat="a in range(12) track by $index" ng-switch="country.Details[ $index ].Population">
    <span ng-switch-when="10000">Medium</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="20000">Large</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="30000">Larger</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="40000">Very Large</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>Error</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is a fiddle which may help you [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/C8LSL/)

```
<tr ng-repeat="details in countries.Details">

                <td ng-repeat="detail in details">{{detail}}</td>
            <td ng-if="details.length<12" ng-repeat="empty in getTempArray(details.length) track by $index">{{empty}}</td>      


      </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood correctly, but I had some problems while using ng-repeat. If your array may have duplicate values then you should `track by $index`.

Try writing inside ng-repeat `countryDetails in country.Details.slice(0, 12) track by $index` instead of `countryDetails in country.Details.slice(0, 12)`